# md5sum change after mount?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext3, hashsum

I have a ext3 filesystem on a .img file. After mounting and unmounting it, I noticed that the md5sum is changed, even if no file inside was changed!

```
md5sum myfilesystem.img
XXXX myfilesystem.img
mount -t ext3 myfilesystem.img temp/
umount temp/
md5sum myfilesystem.img
YYYY myfilesystem.img
```

Why does XXXX differs from YYYY? I clearly didn't touch anything inside myfilesystem.img.

Comment: last mount date is stored :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, if you mount the ext3 in writable mode, there are a few things that get updated, like the last mount date. Try if this also happens when you mount with `-o ro`.

Comment: With -o ro the md5sum is not changed.

Comment: Note that sometimes, even mounting with `-o ro` doesn't guarantee that nothing gets written. See the man page for `mount` under `--read-only`.